# Como pegar os dados de duas tabelas diferentes?

Tags: php

Galera estou com um problema estou fazendo um site no qual pega as imagens de duas tabelas diferentes mas eu so consigo chamar de uma o que eu devo fazer alguem porfavor pode me ajudar?

Comment: O que você já tentou:?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 as t1
LEFT JOIN tabela2 as t2 USING(id)
```

Desta forma, você pega tudo que for das duas tabelas, mas também podes especificar o que você deseja buscar:

```
SELECT
   t1.imagem,
   t1.id,
   t2.imagem,
   t2.id
FROM tabela1 as t1
LEFT JOIN tabela2 as t2 USING(id)
```

Em ambos os casos, dariam certo... Porém, fica um pouco desconfortável elaborar uma resposta exata, com base apenas em textos, e não em informações especificas de sua base de dados.

Comment: é bom utilizar o Join para relacionar tabelas porem eu nunca consigo usa-lo.veja meu codigo

Comment: <!-- Chamando dados do banco -->
<?php
session_start();
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$senha=$_SESSION['senha'];
?>
<?php
include '../php/conexao.php';
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario where email = '$email' and senha = '$senha'") or dile(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);
if($resultado){
  ?>

Comment: <!-- Chamando dados da tabela usuario-->
<img src="<?php echo $row['foto'];?>"/>

Comment: <!--Conectando-se a tabela post-->
<?php 
    $sql="select * from posts"; 
 $res= mysql_query ($sql);
    while ($dados=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
  ?>

Comment: Edite sua questão, e insira o codigo que você já tem, para que possamos conseguir lhe ajudar.

Comment: <!--Chmando dados da tabela post-->
  <?php echo $dados['public'] . "<br>";?>
    <img src="<?php echo $dados['fotopost'];?>" />

Comment: sou novo no site André Baill 3, podes me ajudar?

Comment: Seria bacana você dar uma olhada no tour do site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour pra obter algumas informações extras. A sintaxe seria esta que te mostrei, mas precisava mais informações sobre as tabelas pra conseguir saber ao certo a resposta.